# Is there a way to parse XML with Purescript?

Tags: purescript

I'm looking into functional-programming ways to write a simple web app that does XSLT-like things. I'm thinking about trying Purescript, but I need to make sure it's possible (and relatively easy) to parse XML using it. Is there a way to do that? I found [purescript-xml](https://github.com/unitedvote/purescript-xml) but it seems to be dead (no longer on Pursuit). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple foreign import for [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then used the standard DOM library [purescript-dom](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-dom/4.16.0).

There are bindings in [purescript-domparser](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-domparser/1.0.0/docs/DOM.DOMParser) but I didn't care for them. There is no reason I can discern for representing the DOMParser object.

This is what I used:

```
exports.parseXML = function (s) {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, 'application/xml');
}

foreign import parseXML :: String -> Document
```

Unfortunately, `DOMParser` does not make it straight-forward to determine if parsing failed. On failure, it still returns a valid `Document` but only contains information about the error.